# Getting 'unknown token' using GCM on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have installed GCM in iOS app and everything works fine in Development, I was abel to get push notification. But when I published it to the app store no push notification are coming to the device (works fine in Android).

I installed `PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig` file on my iOS device to see the logs and here is what I saw:

> Received incoming push notification for topic: com.bundle.id but for a
>   completely unknown token XYZ

here are the exact output messages

```
Jun 24 11:45:35 iPhone apsd[103] <Notice>: 2016-06-24 11:45:35 -0700 apsd[103]: Received incoming push notification for topic: com.bundle.id but for a completely unknown token <95af08c3 c74a13bf 6b6fb270 c486f2b3 58989f44 dfe69bc0f 95u410e1 2431b8dc>
Jun 24 11:45:35 iPhone apsd[103] <Notice>: 2016-06-24 11:45:35 -0700 apsd[103]: <APSCourier: 0x137d035e0>: Responding with REMOVED status for message received with topic: 'com.bundle.id' to device token (instead of per-app token)
```

Any idea why this is happening? Why is the token "unknown"? To whom does it belong then?

Comment: Have you tried checking if you have applied the correct implementation of [receiving messages on an iOS client app](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#receiving-messages-on-an-ios-client-app) and [setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)? If you feel like it is a bug, submit them to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues). Here is the [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm) for code reference. Hope this helps.

Comment: What response are you receiving from GCM server? Is it a success? If not, it might be because of the [kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#obtain_a_registration_token) value not set for production?

Comment: as soon as you install your app via testflight or app store, you need a production certificate for push notifications. developer certs only word with debug builds from within xcode.

Comment: This is a very frustrating issue. Just updated an app on the App Store where notifs are working well, and now, on a test device, the first install works perfectly well for ios10, for as long as i use the debug session. If i stop the session and restart, the iOS loses track of the proper token, and uses a cached version that forces the correct one to be unknown, and only delivers the notif to the device and not my app. I restart the device and all is good but this is so odd. It would be ok if the notif would place the sound file requested but it of course cannot find it as it is in the app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried testing your push ***certification***? [Houston](https://github.com/nomad/Houston) on GitHub is often used for certificate testing. Basically if the pushes don't work with the third party then you'll need to re-create your certificates.

**Using Houston in Cli:**

`apn push "<5e8f5cc0 be283f88 cc4ebb7d b6091499 80f51631 5ebf4928 b59a2a62 198d20d0>" -c -out "apple_push_notification.pem" -m "Hello from the command line!"`

***Houston says, ***
We recommend that you upload development cert, production, and any ad-hoc certs.  Layer will automatically determine which cert to use.

**Other potential causes:**

- Are you correctly calling `[layerClient updateRemoteNotificationDeviceToken...]`?
- Are you calling inside `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to send Layer the device token?

You can also check to see if the app is failing to register by implementing `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`. If you look at the error you should be able to figure out why you're not seeing pushes.

**Example Obj-C error check**:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"PUSH ERROR: %@", error);
}
```

**Example Swift error check**:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError!) {
print("PUSH ERROR: \(error)")
}
```

**Potential Xcode/Certificate problem causes:**

- Provisioning profiles are not up-to-date. The device info is stored in the certificates so any time you add a new device to the profile you will need to re-create the profile and certificates.
- Make sure that your XCode Project Settings is pointing the correct Certificate and Provisioning profile.
- When inside the Keychain Access app make sure you are exporting the key AND the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

There two type of certificates provided by the iOS app, one is for development mode and one for the production mode. If you are using the development certificate , the token created are development token  and it not work in the production mode. You have to use the production certificate and create the production token .